# std::unique_ptr::reset and object-specific deleters

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Imagine a `Deleter` that has to stay with its object, as it is somewhat specific to its object. In my case, this is because the deleter uses an allocator library that needs to know the object size when deallocating the memory. Because of inheritance, I cannot simply use `sizeof(T)` but instead need to store the size of the derived object in the deleter on object creation.

```
template<typename T>
struct MyDeleter {

   size_t objectSize;

   MyDeleter() : objectSize(sizeof(T)) {}
   template<typename S>
   MyDeleter(const MyDeleter<S>& other) : objectSize(other.objectSize) 
   // object size is correctly  transferred on assignment ^^^^^^^^^^^
  {}

   void operator(T* t) {
       t->~T();
       coolAllocatorLibrary::deallocate(t, objectSize); 
   // real object size needed for deletion ^^^^^^^^^^
   }
}

template<typename T>
my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, MyDeleter<T>>;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
my_unique_ptr <T> make_my_unique(Args&&... args) {
   T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(coolAllocatorLibrary::allocate(sizeof(T)));
   try {
      new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   } catch(...) {
      coolAllocatorLibrary::deallocate(t, sizeof(T));
      throw;
   }
   return my_unique_ptr <T>(ptr);
}

struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base { 
    uint64_t somePayloadToMakeThisClassBiggerThanItsParent; 
}
```

This works nicely even in case of inheritance: I can safely delete an object of a derived class through a pointer of the super class, as long as the deleter is set correctly in the first place, which is guaranteed as long as `make_my_unique` is used:

```
{
   my_unique_ptr<Base> ptr = make_my_unique<Derived>();
   // Works fine. Here, even though ptr is of type <Base> it will deallocate
   // correctly with sizeof(Derived)  
}
```

The only problematic function is `reset()`, since I can use this function to put in a new pointer without also exchanging the deleter:

```
{
   my_unique_ptr<Base> ptr = make_my_unique<Derived>();
   ptr.reset(new Base()); // OUCH! This will delete the new Base() with sizeof(Derived)
}
```

So, is there any way with which I could make calling `reset` (with a non-`nullptr`) a compile-time error here? This would lead to a safe non-misuable interface.
Either my mental model is wrong, or this is a shortcoming of `std::unique_ptr`, because there doesn't seem to be a way to support this use case with a fully-safe interface.

I would imagine that there could be, e.g., some traits for the deleter where the deleter could disallow calling reset with a non-nullptr, but such things don't seem to exist.

I am aware of the "nuclear option" to just create a totally own `my_unique_ptr` class that has the actual `std::unique_ptr` in it and then exposes only the methods I want, but this is way more effort and it seems that object-specific allocators (e.g., PMRs) should be supported by `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr::reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) has a note on this subject: "_To replace the managed object while supplying a new deleter as well, move assignment operator may be used._"

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Exactly. I want to make sure that move assignment is the *only* way to replace the managed object, so my class cannot be misused by others that expect `my_unique_ptr` to behave like a normal `unique_ptr` and thus expect that it supports the `reset` method without restrictions. (this is not used in a private project but a huge industry project where not everyone understand every piece of code in full detail, so I want to make sure that the compiler helps people to not do the wrong thing)

Comment: There are still wrapper to restrict interface to your use case.

Comment: Would inheriting `unique_ptr` and `delete` the `reset` function be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I guess unique_ptr is not a class that is supposed to be subclassed.

Comment: I guess that is a common view, although, if you never store base class pointers to `unique_ptr` but to your subclass, I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: private inheritance or composition for the wrapping.

Comment: Aside: shouldn't your deleter check for null before destructing through a pointer?

Comment: @Caleth `unique_ptr` guarantees that the deleter isn't called if the pointer is a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unique_ptr has a member type `pointer`which is equal to `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy NullablePointer.
So you may try to add a `pointer` type to your deleter like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyDeleter {
   struct pointer{
       using type = T;
       pointer():_ptr(nullptr){}
       pointer(std::nullptr_t):_ptr(nullptr){}

       //this is required to support creating uniqu_ptr of base class
       template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, typename U::type>, void>>
       pointer(U ptr):_ptr(ptr){}

       T* operator->(){
           return _ptr;
       }

       operator T*() const{
           return _ptr;
       }

    private:
        T *_ptr;
        friend struct MyDeleter;
        explicit pointer(T* ptr):_ptr(ptr){}
   };

   size_t objectSize;

   MyDeleter() : objectSize(sizeof(T)) {}

   template<typename S>
   MyDeleter(const MyDeleter<S>& other) : objectSize(other.objectSize)
  {}

   void operator()(pointer t) {
       t->~T();
       deallocate(t, objectSize); 
   }

   static pointer make_ptr(T* ptr){
       return pointer{ptr};
   }
};

template<typename T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, MyDeleter<T>>;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
my_unique_ptr <T> make_my_unique(Args&&... args) {
   T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(allocate(sizeof(T)));
   try {
      new (ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   } catch(...) {
      deallocate(ptr, sizeof(T));
      throw;
   }
   return my_unique_ptr <T>(MyDeleter<T>::make_ptr(ptr));
}
```

The main idea is to prevent the construction of this pointer wrapper outside of the deleted class. Given this code we will have the following:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base()=default;
    virtual void foo(){std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;}
    int bar{0};
};
struct Derived : Base { 
    uint64_t somePayloadToMakeThisClassBiggerThanItsParent; 
};
struct Derived2 : Base { 
    uint64_t somePayloadToMakeThisClassBiggerThanItsParent; 
    void foo(){std::cout<<"foo2"<<std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    my_unique_ptr<Base> ptr = make_my_unique<Derived>(); //works
    ptr.reset(); //works
    ptr.reset(nullptr); //works
    ptr =  make_my_unique<Derived2>(); //works;
    ptr->foo(); //works
    ptr->bar=2; //works
    *ptr = Base{}; //works if a copy constructor of Base is available
    ptr.reset(new Base()); //does not work. cannot create a pointer wrapper
    ptr.reset(new Derived()); //does not work. cannot create a pointer wrapper. Even with a exact type but created with new.
}
```